# Convert string in array format to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string in this format: `"['A', 'B', 'C']"`. I want to convert it to an array `['A', 'B', 'C']`. I tried using `JSON.parse()` but it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const strArray = "['A', 'B', 'C']";
const parsedString = JSON.parse(strArray);
console.log(parsedString);
```

Comment: do you have other single or double quotes in the strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to a valid json by replacing the single quotes with double quotes and parse:

```js
const str = "['A', 'B', 'C']";

const result = JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution would be to change the format of your datasource to be valid JSON(`"` instead of `'`):

```
 JSON.parse('["A", "B", "C"]')
```

However, if that is not an option, you can do that programmaticaly for sure:

```
JSON.parse("['A', 'B', 'C']".replace(/'/, '"'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let string = "['A', 'B', 'C']";
JSON.parse(string.replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

The error with JSON.parse is because JSON requires `"` and not `'`