# TO convert a string to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a String like

```
var str =  "['one','two']"
```

i want to convert it into a array, what are the possibilities ?

is there a elegant solution than stripping quotes

Comment: Use str.split();

Comment: If possible, it's would be worth trying to avoid this situation to begin with (and get the data in a non-string format), rather than trying to rescue it with string parsing.

Comment: replace single quotes with double quotes.`JSON.parse("['one','two']".replace(/'/g,'"'))`

Comment: you could take a [JSON](http://json.org/) compliant string with double quotes inside and simply parse this JSON.

Comment: it will give an array with [0] = "['one'   and [1] as 'two']"      this is not what i want. Hemant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string in array format to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504013/convert-string-in-array-format-to-javascript-array) and [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace()` and `split()` methods:

```js
var str = "['one','two']";
str = str.replace( /[\[\]']+/g, '' );

var strarr = str.split( ',' );
console.log( strarr )
```